# how to extract values from an objects nested inside array JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
[{
    "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fb",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fc",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fd",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64559",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e6455a",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Quick overview: each object contains a different conversation data. I want to extract the names, id, messages out of each conversation and store them in a separate object. for instance:

```
[{
  "id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa"
  "contacts": [dean, john, brad],
  "messages": []
 },

 {
  "id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558"
  "contacts": [dean, brad],
  "messages": []
 }]
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

U can use `map`. Let's name your array as `array`

```
let newArray = array.map(a => {
  return {
    id: a._id,
    contacts: a.contacts.map(contact => contact.name)
    messages: messages
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using reduce,

```js
const arr = [{
    "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fa",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fb",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fc",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd6288a155cda5a10d067fd",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64558",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e64559",
            "id": "5fd35931ec23f76d387d8464",
            "name": "dean"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd63ab97aac3826f8e6455a",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "brad"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 0
}]

let res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   curr.contacts = curr.contacts.map(item => item.name);
   const { _id, contacts, messages } = curr;
   acc.push({
      _id,
      contacts,
      messages,
   });
   
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```